# Powershell replace characters in files within sub-directories using -LiteralPath

Tags: powershell

I want to replace bad characters in filenames within all sub-directories.  However due to limitation of rename-item with '[' (wild cards) I have to use the
-LiteralPath in the command.  This means I'm having issues with running this with sub-directories.

The code below works on current directory, but I cannot work out how to adapt this code to rename files within all sub-directories.  Please help?

```
ls *.* -recurse | % { Move-Item -literalpath $_.fullname `
($_.name -replace "[()\[\]]|\.(?!\w{3}$)", " ") }
```

Comment: `ls *.* -Recurse |Move-Item {$_.Name -replace '[()\[\]]|\.(?!\w{3}$)', ' '}` will bind the objects from `ls` to `Move-Ite -LiteralPath $_.PSPath` implicitly, no need to use `% { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Your RegEx will remove the dot's from extensions with not exactly 3 chars.

```
.h
.cs
.html
```

I suggest replacing in BaseName and append the extension and only if brackets/parentheses/dots chars are present.

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -Recurse -File|
  Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '[()\[\]\.]'}|
    Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace '[()\[\]\.]',' ')+$_.Extension} -Whatif
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` if the output looks OK.